# Gitgub Login with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, oauth-2.0, github-api

Thank you for taking the time to ask my question.

I want to retrieve user ID and commit history through GitHub social login.

But I'm not finding a suitable example in SwiftUI.

There were many examples with UIkit, but the login part was implemented but the information receiving part failed.

So I'm trying to solve the problem using a method.

```swift
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class GitHubOAuthManager: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = GitHubOAuthManager()

    private let clientID = "MYclientID"
    private let clientSecret = "MYclientSecret"
    private let redirectURL = "MYredirectURL"
    private var accessToken: String?

    @Published var user: GitHubUser?

    private init() {}

    func initiateGitHubLogin() {
        let authURL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize" +
                      "?client_id=\(clientID)" +
                      "&redirect_uri=\(redirectURL)" +
                      "&scope=user"

        if let url = URL(string: authURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    func handleRedirectURL(_ url: URL) {
        guard let code = url.queryParameters?["code"] else {
            print("Failed to get authorization code")
            return
        }

        requestAccessToken(with: code)
    }

    private func requestAccessToken(with code: String) {
        let tokenURL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"

        let parameters = [
            "client_id": clientID,
            "client_secret": clientSecret,
            "code": code,
            "redirect_uri": redirectURL
        ]

        AF.request(tokenURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            .responseDecodable(of: GitHubAccessTokenResponse.self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let accessTokenResponse):
                    self.accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken
                    self.fetchGitHubUserData()
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failed to get access token: \(error)")
                }
            }
    }

    private func fetchGitHubUserData() {
        guard let accessToken = accessToken else {
            print("Access token is nil")
            return
        }

        let userURL = "https://api.github.com/user"

        AF.request(userURL, headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"])
            .responseDecodable(of: GitHubUser.self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let user):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.user = user
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failed to fetch user data: \(error)")
                }
            }
    }
}


extension URL {
    var queryParameters: [String: String]? {
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
              let queryItems = components.queryItems else {
            return nil
        }

        var parameters = [String: String]()
        queryItems.forEach {
            parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
        }

        return parameters
    }
}
```

I would like to implement a social login page through a button and display user information when login is successful.

Comment: ebut the information receiving part failed." What do you mean by that?  Is `print("Failed to fetch user data: \(error)")` called?